# Pageinit not firing when user clicks back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back, page-init

I am using JQM to create and app however I want to keep some history so the user can go back however it seems on one page when I go back to it it fails to load the ajax. All my pages are external and loads in the `pageinit` event. It should be noted that this same structure of code works for all other pages except this one however it is not an error that I can see in the code. Please see code below:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Music App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/music.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/soundmanager2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--load all songs by genre-->
    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="genretracks">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Genre Tracks</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search list..." id="genretracklist">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $(document).on( "pageinit", "#genretracks", function( e ) {
var passedId = (passDataObject.selectedHref != null ? passDataObject.selectedHref : window.location.href).replace( /.*id=/, "" );
var surl =  "http://localhost/musicapp/includes/genretracks.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    data:  "Genre="+passedId,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "genretrackscallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    }).done(function(){ 
        $("a").bind("click",function(){
            passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;
        }); 
    }).fail(function(){ 
        alert("$.get failed!"); //replace with failed dialog 
    })
});


 function genretrackscallback(rtndata) 
 { 
var data="";
for(j=0;j<=rtndata.length -1;j++)
{
    data = data + "<li><a href='./player.html?id="+rtndata[j].track_id+"' data-transition='slide' id="+rtndata[j].track_name+"><h3>" + rtndata[j].track_name + "</h3><p><strong>" + rtndata[j].artist_name + "</strong></p><p>" + rtndata[j].genre_name + "</p></a></li>";
}
$('#genretracklist').html(data);
$('#genretracklist').listview('refresh'); 
 }
```

When I click on the an item in the list created by the function above it fires another javascript function based on the id and carries the user to another external page. This all works fine however when the user presses back the function above doesn't fire or fires once after several attempts. How can I ensure that this function fires when the user is going back?

Comment: Tell me why are you using pageinit event? It triggers only once (unless page is refreshed). Also tell me, do you still use ajax to load pages into the DOM?

Comment: @Gajotres no I didn't disable ajax to load the pages.

Comment: Then take a look at my answer below. If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @Gajotres I did and also left a comment it works for an alert but the ajax function doesn't insert anything into the DOM

Comment: I have added another content to my answer, take a look.

Comment: @Gajotres am not seeing your old solution or the new one

Comment: Ok so I found what the issue is. It seems that the line `var passedId = (passDataObject.selectedHref != null ? passDataObject.selectedHref : window.location.href).replace( /.*id=/, "" );` which gets the id from the url does't work properly when hitting the back button. Is there a better way to get the id from the url in jqm and html.